# Não consigo realizar um RedirectToAction para uma Area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Print do que já realizei, porém não funcionou, este é meu LoginController.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha estrutura, e estou tentando apontar para o PacienteController/Index:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma das outras opções que tentei, foi adicionar rotas em startups.cs.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "areas",
                  template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Paciente}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
            });
```

Comment: Teste `RedirectToAction("Index", "Paciente", new {  area = "Paciente" })`

Comment: Note que ASP.NET MVC não é a mesma coisa ASP.NET Core. Outra coisa: poste sempre o código em texto formatado, não em imagens. Isso ajuda na visualização, na indexação da pergunta e não impede quem tem bloqueios de entender a pergunta.

Comment: Prefira postar o código em texto ao invés de imagem. O motivo está [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485).

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann não funcionou não, :C

Comment: Você pode adicionar as configurações das areas mapeadas nas rotas do startup?

Comment: Já tentei, utilizei este código:
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "areas",
                  template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Paciente}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
            });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou mostrar o que eu fiz para funcionar, verifique no seu projeto:

Primeiro adicionar a rota no startup:

```
  app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {

            routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "MinhasAreas",
                    template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Atribuir os controllers dentro de suas respectivas areas:

```
[Area("Paciente")]
public class PacienteController : Controller
{
    // GET: /<controller>/
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Realizar o redirecionamento normalmente:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult GravarCadastro(string perfil) {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", perfil, new { area = perfil });
    }
}
```

Adicionei o projeto no github para consulta, basta clicar em login e escolher o perfil para ser redirecionado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Link do projeto:

https://github.com/superrfm/aspnetcore_areas

Comment: Muito bom Rafael